# Sencha for Android

Tags: android, extjs

I am new to sencha and android.

I want to develope android apps using sencha,i heard that sencha is a good platform for developing mobile apps. So please can anyone guide me to start and i have already gone through the documentation but am confused about which tool we should use to develope for mobile apps and what is the correct procedure.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I believe Sencha has it's own tool you can use. But Stack Overflow isn't supposed to be used for asking for tool recommendations. It is for programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

My experience:

**1.Watch videos from Official site**

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/video

**2.Understand MVC architecture in Sencha**

**3.Search specific topic on youtube and learn from it**

**4.Find a useful Editor.**

I use Aptana studio 3 which is a Eclipse plugin and it also have a standalone version. The following link shows you how to add code assist in Aptana.
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112540-Aptana-Code-Assist-for-Sencha-Touch&p=635681&viewfull=1#post635681

**5.Practice more**

ps. If you want to control your device more, you'll need **phonegap** to access your device.
http://phonegap.com/

Comment: ThanQ so much for your suggestions